# Discrepancy between _Open data view and Tracking Open list (inferred opens)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-tracking

Sorry if this question had been asked before. In short we found that the Unique Open amount on the tracking page is different to the amount shown in _open data view (we count distinct Subscribers).

Basically we have a nightly automated job to extract _open data view and loaded everything into the database. Then at the end of the email campaign we want to build some reports based on the data extracted.

We then found some subscribers in the _Open data view could not be found from the Unique Open list on the tracking page.

From investigation we found that in history activities these subscribers have "Click" event but do not have "Open" event. So it seems that in the _Open data view "click" also means "Open", but it won't be counted as "Open" on the tracking page

Does it mean the _Open data view is using a different logic to the tracking page?

Comment: Open counter in SFMC is based on the counter tag being rendered in an email client.  It's essentially a pixel being loaded.  Click tracking is done at the specific link click, which does inherently give you a portion of the openers.  Since there are so many different esp and firewalls within your audience, you should expect not to have an exact 1-1 ratio.  There will be some contacts that may not have rendered the counter properly.

Comment: @TomCallahan Hi Tom, Thanks for your response. But probably I didn't explain the scenario clearly. So the scenario is, during the email campaign we have an extraction of _Open data view, in which we have subscriber A. Then after few weeks, we went to the tracking page of the Job, and found that subscriber A is in "Did not open" list, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: How are you extracting the Open DV? Query DV to DE then export DE or Tracking Extract to FTP? Tracking Extracts include an option for 'inferred' opens, which is likely the discrepancy you are seeing.

Comment: @Gortonington Thanks for the help. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Moving from Comment to Answer for easier reference**

---

Tracking Extracts include an option for ['inferred' opens](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5), which is likely the discrepancy you are seeing.

From Documentation:
[image: IncludeInferredOpens]

Basically an inferred open is when there is a click associated with a subscriber without a recorded open (e.g. if images are blocked).  **Inferred opens are not included inside of any UI tracking and Data Views**. I believe these are only available via the Tracking Extract or if you manually create a record of them via SQL queries.